# Remove duplicate value when we use rollup

Tags: mysql

How to remove duplicate value when we use rollup in mysql?

I have a table like

```
+------+--------+----------+------------+
| id | open_bal | closing_bal | balance |
+------+--------+----------+------------+
| 1 |      5005.00 |3005.00 | 8005.00   |
| 2 |      5004.00 |3004.00 | 8004.00   |
| 3 |      5003.00 |3003.00 | 8003.00   |
| 4 |      5002.00 |3002.00 | 8002.00   |
| 5 |      5001.00 |3001.00 | 8001.00   |
| 6 |      500.00  | 300.00 | 800.00    |
+------+--------+----------+|-----------+
```

and I got result like this

```
+------+--------+----------+------------+
| id | open_bal | closing_bal | balance |
+------+--------+----------+------------+
| 6 |      500.00  |300.00  | 800.00    |
| 6 |      500.00  |NULL    | 800.00    |
| 5 |      5001.00 |3001.00 | 8001.00   |
| 5 |      5001.00 |NULL    | 8001.00   |
| 4 |      5002.00 |3002.00 | 8002.00   |
| 4 |      5002.00 |NULL    | 8002.00   |
| 3 |      5003.00 |3003.00 | 8003.00   |
| 3 |      5003.00 |NULL    | 8003.00   |
| 2 |      5004.00 |3004.00 | 8004.00   |
| 2 |      5004.00 |NULL    | 8004.00   |
| 1 |      5005.00 |3005.00 | 8005.00   |
| 1 |      5005.00 | NULL   | 8005.00   |
| 1 |      NULL    | NULL   | 15315.00  |
+------+--------+----------+|-----------+
```

And my desired result is like this

```
+------+--------+----------+------------+
| id | open_bal | closing_bal | balance |
+------+--------+----------+------------+
| 1 |      5005.00 |3005.00 | 8005.00   |
| 2 |      5004.00 |3004.00 | 8004.00   |
| 3 |      5003.00 |3003.00 | 8003.00   |
| 4 |      5002.00 |3002.00 | 8002.00   |
| 5 |      5001.00 |3001.00 | 8001.00   |
| 6 |      500.00  | 300.00 | 800.00    |
|   |              |        |15315.00   |
+------+--------+----------+|-----------+
```

Table structure is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE `billing_account` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `goid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `open_bal` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `closing_bal` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `modified_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The Query that I wrote:

```
SELECT   open_bal, balance, SUM(closing_bal)
FROM     `billing_account`
GROUP BY open_bal, balance
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: why are you grouping by open_bal, balance? Isn't there any common field, maybe an account_id?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UNION:

> ```
> SELECT open_bal, closing_bal, balance
> FROM `billing_account`
> UNION
> SELECT NULL, NULL, sum(closing_bal)
> FROM `billing_account`
> ```
>
> ```
> open_bal | closing_bal |  balance
> -------: | ----------: | -------:
>  5005.00 |     3005.00 |  8005.00
>  5004.00 |     3004.00 |  8004.00
>  5003.00 |     3003.00 |  8003.00
>  5002.00 |     3002.00 |  8002.00
>  5001.00 |     3001.00 |  8001.00
>   500.00 |      300.00 |   800.00
>     null |        null | 15315.00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=826a31ada43f5b0e1d4ab4c1a0d3abea)*